# Standardization for PCA/FA

Tags: statistics

I did PCA/FA analysis with and without standardization and end up with different results. For standardization, I just divided each input variable by its corresponding standard deviation. However, I have not subtracted the mean (as in case of Z-scores). My question is how important it is to subtract the mean in case of PCA/FA?

I found on another blog that dividing by std dev is another way of standardizing the data-set. Is this superior to z-scores in any sense? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, principal components try to capture highest **variation** in the data; The important point is that, variation in here is defined as the **2nd norm**; *not variance and not standard deviation*;

For example the first principal component is the linear combination of data in the direction given by:

[image: w1]

This matters a lot because

1. unlike variance, 2nd norm is sensitive to location; in other words, if you add a constant to a vector, the variance will not change but the 2nd norm will change;
2. unlike standard deviation, 2nd norm is sensitive to scale; i.e. if a vector is multiplied by a constant factor, 2nd norm will scale by that factor;

There are at least two problems if an analysis is impacted by location and scale of explanatory factors:

1. In reality, observations represent different phenomena, so they have different and incomparable scale and average; for example the variations and average income values are not comparable with variations and average age of a sample population;
2. You do not want the model results conceptually change if for example incomes are quoted in cents as opposed to dollars, or measurements are done in inches and feet as opposed to meters;

But, plain PCA is sensitive to scale and location; for example, this is a PCA analysis on two dimensional standard normal variables with correlation `.4`;

[image: pca1]

The red lines represents the direction of loading vectors; Obviously the first principal component is capturing the highest variation in the joint data, and correctly gives equal shares to each vector;

But things will change dramatically if we move the population 2 units to the right; (equivalent of increasing the average of the first vector by 2 units):

[image: pca2]

Technically we have the same data as before, but now the first principal component is basically capturing the fact that the first vector has non-zero mean;

Similarly, if the first vector is scaled by a factor of 2:

[image: pca3]

As can be seen, the first vector has got 4 times more weight than the second vector, simply driven by the fact that it has higher variance.

This shows the importance of normalizing scale and removing mean value from the data before doing PCA;

That said, still one can come up with *certain* situations that the relative location and scale of the explanatory factors have useful information in the analysis and they should not be wiped out of the data.

Comment: Thank you very for the detailed answer. This clears a lot of things.